# Probability Distribution of H-T when a coin is tossed 10 times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

When a coin is tossed 10 times, how probability distribution will look like?

I answer,

As all possibilities are: **0H 10T;
1H 9T;
2H 8T;
3H 7T;
4H 6T;
5H 5T;
6H 4T;
7H 3T;
8H 2T;
9H 1T;
10H 0T;**

**Z = H-T: -10 -8 -6 -4 -2 0 2 4 6 8 10**

**P(X=x): $1/2^{10}$ for each of them**

But with this distribution Variance will come out to be **440/$2^{10}$** but actual variance is **10**
**So, This distribution is definitely wrong.**

Can someone please tell why this distribution is wrong?

Some Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not consider the order of results?  (i.e. Is HHHHHHHHHT the same results as THHHHHHHHH or any othe permutation of 9 heads and 1 tail?)

Comment: @S.A.Lloyd My bad I just did it while taking the order is account, It was a silly mistake.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only counting each possibility once, when there are actually ${10 \choose n}$ sequences such that that $H=n$, out of a sample space of size $|\Omega|=2^{10}$. The number of heads has expected value $\mathbb{E}(H) = 5$, and $Z = H - T = H - (10 - H) = 10-2H$.

Thus, $\mathrm{Var}(Z) = \mathrm{Var}(2H) = 4\mathrm{Var}(H)$. And so,

$$\mathrm{Var}(Z) = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{10}\mathbb{P}(H=n)\cdot(n-\mathbb{E}(H))^2 =4 \sum_{n=0}^{10}(n-5)^2\frac{{10 \choose n}}{2^{10}}=10$$